# sibling() in js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just starting out learning javascript along with jquery. I have a set of events which trigger the same function. I pass the value of `this` into the function ($t). I have two main lines of code. One of which works as it uses `this` as the selector, but the other I need to use the equivalent of "this p". Ie select `this` (a div) and all the `p` s within it. I've tried:

```
$($t).css({"background-color": "rgba(30,30,30,0.5)"});
$($t p).css({"color": "#ffffff"});
```

and

```
$($t).css({"background-color": "rgba(30,30,30,0.5)"});
$($t).sibling("p").css({"color": "#ffffff"});
```

but I can't seem to get it to work. The top css command works, but the sibling one doesn't. This is exactly how it appears in my code. No commands inbetween them.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: The method is `siblings()`, not `sibling()`, the latter of which would have thrown an error in your console. Always check the console before moving on to other troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select "this" (a div) and all the "p"s **within it.**

```
$('p', $t).css({"color": "#ffffff"});
```

which is short for :

```
$($t).find('p').css({"color": "#ffffff"});
```

`siblings()` will select... wait for it ..... siblings, not elements within the element, that would be `find()`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$("p",$t).css({"color": "#ffffff"});
```

or

```
$($t).find( "p").css({"color": "#ffffff"});
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses. This is still a learning process for me. Although I've got the hang of php as it's closer to what I'm already used too, I've only just started using js and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
$($t).find('p').css({"color": white});
```

And For Later Try Reading Jquery Documents in [Here](http://api.jquery.com/)